# Turtlebot Computer has OpenCV 3.0 and I don't want it

Tags: catkin-make, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I need openCV 2.4 (since I am using indigo). But my turtlebot has 3.0, making conflicts during catkin_make. How do I remove OpenCV 3.0, or at least, how do I built against OpenCV 2.4?
OpenCV 3.0 was install locally, so I cannot use sudo apt-get remove.

I found all the libopencv-....so.3.0.0, but I don't know if removing all those libraries will solve the problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247221/turtlebot-computer-has-opencv-3.0-and-i-don%27t-want-it/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just removed everything related to OpenCV 3.0 from the /usr/local/ folder, recompiled ROS workspace, and problem solved!!!!!!!!!

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
Explicitly specifying version 2 as a requirement to `find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)` could also have worked, although I've seen other users still having problems when using that approach.